# C++ Change address of array element

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, element

I'm writing a function to combine m x m blocks into an n x n matrix. The blocks are a 3d pointer array `B[BlockIndex][BlockRow][BlockColumn]`, and the n x n matrix is a 2d pointer array `M[Row][Column]`. If M is 4x4 and B is 4 2x2 matrices then `BlockIndex = 0` is the top-left block, `BlockIndex = 1` is the top-right, `BlockIndex = 2` is the bottom-left, and `BlockIndex = 3` is the bottom right.

I'd like to just point elements of M to the beginnings of rows of the appropriate blocks, but I can't seem (nor do I know if it's possible) to set the address of an element `[i][j]` of M. I can set `M[i]` to `B[BlockIndex][i]` so that (using the 2x2 and 4x4 example) the first 2 elements of the ith row of M point to the ith row of the BlockIndex-th block, but how can I point the third element of the ith row of M to the ith row of the (BlockIndex+1)-th block?

I understanding I'm kind of contradicting the idea of contiguous memory here, as I'm taking an array of 4 elements (the ith row of M) that exist side-by-side in memory and trying to break that sequence by pointing the last 2 elements of that array to a different array of 2 elements. However, If I can get away with this then it'll save time when the matrices get huge, since I don't want to resort to deep-copying B to M element-wise. I also realize I may be misusing "deep copy" here...

To clarify, I want to (basically) change the address of elements of an array `X` that are not the first element to that of (the first element of) a different arrays `Y,Z`. After this operation, as you iterate of the elements of `X` you would be accessing different sets of sequential memory, `X...Y...Z`.

Below is the current incarnation of the function I'm writing to split/combine matrices into/from smaller blocks.

Thanks,

Tim

```
bool    SplitCombineMat(double** &Mat, double*** &Blocks, int const& MatSize,
                                int const& BlockSize, bool const& SplitMatrix)
{
    bool IsOk = true;

    if (SplitMatrix)
        IsOk = PrepareBlocks(Blocks, MatSize, BlockSize);

    if (IsOk)
    {
        //  Set the beginnings (pointers) of the rows of blocks
        //  to the right elements of Mat.
        //  This is a shallow copy.
        int BlockIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= MatSize - BlockSize ; i += BlockSize)
            for (int j = 0 ; j <= MatSize - BlockSize ; i += BlockSize){
                for (int k = 0 ; k < BlockSize ; k++)
                    if (SplitMatrix)
                        Blocks[BlockIndex][k] = &Mat[k+i][j];
                    else    //  Here want to use pointers as above but can't figure it out...
                            //  Something like -- &Mat[k+i][j] = Blocks[BlockIndex][k];
                        for (int l = 0 ; l < BlockSize ; l++)
                            Mat[k+i][l] = Blocks[BlockIndex][k][l];
                BlockIndex++;
            }
    }

    return IsOk;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible in C++. As you said, an array is a contigous area of memory and you can't have it continue from another address in the middle.

Also, you can't "change" the address of an array, it's a constant. You can, however, use arrays of pointers but in your case, it wouldn't work either. The only option is to copy the contents of the arrays.

There might be some non-standard vector class which lets you do this, but then your accesses to the arrays will be slow.

I think just copying everything shouldn't be too much of a problem for performance. Most probably, generating the initial blocks (or reading them in) will dominate the copying time. Cheers.